# Do i have an infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code:

```
i = len(s) - 1
while i >=0:
    if silaba_final(s[i:]):
        if i == 0:
            return True
        else:
            z = len(s) - i
            while z >=0:
                if not e_silaba(s[z:i]):
                    z = z - 1
                if e_silaba(s[z:i]):
                    if z == 0:
                        return True
                    else:
                        z = len(s) - z
    if not silaba_final(s[i:]):
        if i == 0:
            return False
        else:
             i = i - 1
```

So i have this code it is suposed to see if a word contains a "silaba_final"
    then the rest of the word except that "silaba_final"... can contain zero
    or more times the fuction "e_silaba". I tried this code but when i execute 
    it gives "Executing command. Please wait for result" I suppose its an 
    infinite loop. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you run it through a profiler, or just execute it with some print statements to see what was going on?

Comment: Have you tried debugging (either through a debugger, or using print statements) to see what's happening?

Comment: ye can't really see whats wrong in here

Answer (score 1):

You will indeed end up with an infinite loop in this code if `silaba_final(s[i:])` is true and `i > 0`. Your statement `i = i - 1` will only ever be reached if `silaba_final(s[i:])` is false.

Comment: That looks correct to me, and a solution would be to delete the last `else:` then unindent the `i = i + 1` two levels.

Comment: So i should add a statement to stop the loop?

Comment: It's hard to answer that question without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish.